# How should I judge that the flash has been loaded completed

Tags: flash, swfobject

In our website, I embed a flash produced by flash builder in html , and the size of flash is more than 2M. Because of the bad network, it may be spent 30 seconds to load the flash. How should i know the flash has been loaded completely by browser?

Comment: you should consider a preloader. load a small swf with a loader bar that loads and displays the progress of your 2M swf.

Answer (score 1):

You can poll the SWF to get its `PercentLoaded` value.

Here's one way to do it (code copied from [learnswfobject.com](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/executing-javascript-when-the-swf-has-finished-loading/)):

```
function swfLoadEvent(fn){
    //Ensure fn is a valid function
    if(typeof fn !== "function"){ return false; }
    //This timeout ensures we don't try to access PercentLoaded too soon
    var initialTimeout = setTimeout(function (){
        //Ensure Flash Player's PercentLoaded method is available and returns a value
        if(typeof e.ref.PercentLoaded !== "undefined" && e.ref.PercentLoaded()){
            //Set up a timer to periodically check value of PercentLoaded
            var loadCheckInterval = setInterval(function (){
                //Once value == 100 (fully loaded) we can do whatever we want
                if(e.ref.PercentLoaded() === 100){
                    //Execute function
                    fn();
                    //Clear timer
                    clearInterval(loadCheckInterval);
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
    }, 200);
}

//This function is invoked by SWFObject once the <object> has been created
var callback = function (e){

    //Only execute if SWFObject embed was successful
    if(!e.success || !e.ref){ return false; }

    swfLoadEvent(function(){

        //Put your code here
        alert("The SWF has finished loading!");

    });

};

swfobject.embedSWF("movie.swf", "flashcontent", "550", "400", "9", false, false, false, false, callback);
```

Comment: what does e mean here in function swfLoadEvent?

Comment: it's an event handler, part of the swfobject callback system. See http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/the-callback-function/ and http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api#swfobject.embedSWF(swfUrlStr,_replaceElemIdStr,_widthStr,_height

Answer (score 0):

pipwerks answer is working fine.
you can even get lower value: instead of 1500 only 100 will be ok.

but i experienced some issues on Firefox.
instead of a timeout, initialTimeout  should be a timeInterval, because on FF sometimes, at first call you'll have e.ref.PercentLoaded undefined, but next call will be fine.
of course you need to call clearInterval(initialTimeout); when if is true.

so you'll get somehting like:

```
    var initialTimeout = setInterval(function (){
     if(typeof e.ref.PercentLoaded !== "undefined" && e.ref.PercentLoaded()){
         clearInterval(initialTimeout);
```