# Negative result from PercentLoaded on large swf files

Tags: javascript, flash

I use some javascript on the website I'm working on to check if a swf file is loaded. I use the PercentLoaded method like explained here [How should I judge that the flash has been loaded completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490662/how-should-i-judge-that-the-flash-has-been-loaded-completed)

It works well except that sometimes the file loads until about 50-70% and then PercentLoaded starts to return negative values. This seems to only happen with really large swf files, usually bigger than 30MB.

Is there a reason to that? Is it a known issue? Is there a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue, mine starts to put negative value after 50%, so i decided to test on the value of PercenLoaded(), id it's negative i add 100 :

```
                    loadingValue = e.ref.PercentLoaded();

                    if(loadingValue < 0){
                        loadingValue = e.ref.PercentLoaded() + 100;
                    }
```